# Showing/Hiding the main form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am working on a program where clicking on a button on form1 will open form2. I will then hide form1 until form2 is closed. The problem I have is that I cannot get form1 to show after form2 closes. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
        try
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
            AddGradeForm = new Form2(Form.NumberOfSelections);
            AddGradeForm.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show(AddGradeForm.Result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
            AddGradeForm.Dispose();
            AddGradeForm = new Form2(Form.NumberOfSelections);
            AddGradeForm.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show(AddGradeForm.Result.ToString());
        }
        Form1.ActiveForm.Show();
```

ERROR: NullReferenceException was unhanded. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I don't think `try`...`catch` does what you think it does...

Comment: Im using the try..catch to dispose of the previous Form2 if it was already created. It's for in case the user decides to open form2 multiple times. I know that I should put AddGradeForm.Dispose() somewhere else, but I am still working on structuring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because there is no active form anymore, you've hidden the one that could be active.  This has other side effects, your app will lose the focus.  What you need to do is keep track of the previously active form and get it to show again *before* the dialog closes.  Like this:

```
        var prior = Form.ActiveForm;
        using (var dlg = new Form2()) {
            dlg.FormClosing += delegate { prior.Show(); };
            prior.Hide();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                MessageBox.Show("result");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why did you use FormClosing event? dlg can be stopped from hiding by some other handler and nevertheless prior would be shown. Isn't it better to use FormClosed event?

Comment: FormClosed is too late.  Your app will lose the focus.  If the dialog can cancel the close then you'll need to give it another event that you can subscribe to.

Comment: +1 beat me to it and I was right behind you with code on the clipboard =)

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be:

```
Form1.Show();
```

Comment: There is no such method for Form1

Comment: Form1 is a *type name*, not a reference to a form class.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Show();
```

should be

```
Form1.Show();
```

Also note that it may not be called if there's an exception. wrap it in a finally block if you want it to be called.

```
    try
    {
        Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        Form1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a .Show() method for Form1. That's why I am using Form1.ACtiveForm.Show();

Comment: You're right, didn't notice it was a type name, and just assumed it was an instance. Upvoted yours.