# Close Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a simple app using c# Windows forms. The main form open another form, but i dont want the both forms. I want it that when the second form opens the first form closes. Since the first form is the main using

```
    this.Close();
```

after showing the second form will close the both. So i used this instead

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         frmData QS = new frmData();
         QS.Show();
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
         this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    private void frmData_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I want to know if there is any other way to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can hide the form instead as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702070/showing-hiding-the-main-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not pass your main form as argument to `Application.Run`:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

MainForm frmMain = new MainForm();
frmMain.Show();

Application.Run();
```

Thus you will be able to close it when showing another form:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmData QS = new frmData();
     QS.Show();
     this.Close();
}
```

To close application you should use

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky this.close terminates the App.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel really? How main form related to app life?

Comment: +1 Just understood the edited code..Already removed my comment. This is what i was looking for..THANKS!!!!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes just tried. only mainform, I created one more form, called show, then closed first form app terminates

Comment: @SriramSakthivel take a look on `Program.cs` file. You will find main form instance passed to `Application.Run` method. There is no other way to kill app by closing form

Comment: @No i just removed, I never knew about this, got curious and tried. have you tried this before?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sure. Main form just needed for default application context. It subscribes to form closing event and raises `ThreadExit` event to close application. You can close application manually, or create your own context, which will raise that event on some weird conditions

Answer (score 3):

Hide the first form.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmData QS = new frmData();
     QS.Show();
     this.Hide();
}

private void frmData_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to the answer. Exactly like i would have answered!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no possible way to close the main form if you close the main form it closes all forms of the same project. You can only hide it.

BTW you can open and show a form in only one simple line like this: `new FormName().Show();`