# Kill a specific Form

Tags: c#, forms

I require assistance on killing a specific form.

This is what I have:

```
new Login().Show(); // opens the Login form

this.Hide(); // hides this form, but keeps it running which is bad.
```

I have tried `Environment.Exit(0);` but this kills the application. I only want to kill the form, and it cannot still be running.

Comment: totally unclear but, _this.Close()_

Comment: @Steve when I run this, it kills the application. Not the Form

Comment: So _this_ is the main form of your application and closing it closes the application by design. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820995/close-main-form I don't understand why you show your main form and then decide to hide it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  Login form

```
this.close();
```

or in main or other form

```
var f = new Login();
f.Show(); //Shows form
f.Close(); //Closes form
```