How to make a c# WinForm app with independent windows
I have a WinForm app in c# written with Visual Studio. The main window's form class is called Form1 (very original!). File / New should create a new independent window or instance of the app. I started with
    private void newToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var newForm = new Form1(Countforms);
      newForm.Show();
    }

That works except that all windows close when the first closes.
I also tried copying from Program.cs with
    private void newToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

but that gets an error with
Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation.
Program.cs is standard issue, it was:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Life
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}

I tried removing [STAThread] that did not help.
I also tried various ways of breaking the parent / child link between the forms. E.g. Parent = null; Owner = null in the constructor.
The only thing I could think of was to have a dummy main form which is always invisible and which launches a Form1 immediately. Form1s can then count in and out as new windows are created / closed. The dummy main form closes when the Form1 count gets to zero. There is a question using Delphi Berlin VCL which suggests that would work. And it does.
Is there a better way to have 'independent' windows firing off from File / New?
Maybe I need a different way of starting the project / application.

it actually sounds like you want to start a new instance of your program and not only an independent window...

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17821108/56778

This: Application.Run(new Form1()) doesn't actually run a Form, it generates a default ApplicationContext, where the instance of the Form specified is the treated as the MainForm, which defines, in a way, the lifetime of the application. When this Form closes, the ApplicationContext ends the message loop. You can run your own ApplicationContext, with its own rules. Example here (you can find many others). That ApplicationContext doesn't even have a Form, just a ContextMenuStrip

A much simpler approach is to never call Application.Run: simply ensure that the most recent window is displayed with ShowDialog() method, like here, otherwise stay in loop. Alternatively call all windows with Show() and calling DoEvent() yourself? Not sure, that probably looses to dedicated context.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form

Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-9.0

The first window an application opens becomes the "main window", all subsequent windows opened on the same thread becomes child windows. Closing the main window also closes all its childs.
One approach to avoid this is to make a hidden main window, i.e. create a new form and set visible to false in the OnLoad method, and make sure this is the first window to be loaded. Since the window is hidden the user cannot close it easily. Just do not forget to write code to actually terminate the entire application once the last child window is closed.
You could also use different processes or threads to show each window. The problem with both methods is that it makes interaction between windows much more difficult. If you use multiple processes you need to send messages between them if. If you use multiple threads you need to ensure you are only updating an UI object on the thread that owns it, and this can be difficult enough with just one UI thread, let alone multiple. Ofc, if you are 100% sure no window will ever need to communicate with any other this should not be an issue.

Use multi-threading to solve this problem. This method creates new form thread with no connection to main thread.
// namespace required
using System.Threading;


private void  newToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Thread independent_thread = new Thread(newFormStart);
independent_thread.Start();
}

void newFormStart()
{
Application.Run(new Form1());
}


That works perfectly. Secondary threads / instances are accessible to debugger.

You can launch a new process to create a really independent form: a new instance of app.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("WindowsFormsApp1.exe"); // Your .exe
}


That works but the secondary instances are not accessible to debugger.

@GeorgeKeeling You need to explicitly attach the debugger to any additional instances.
